# What are the conditionals for the following tree diagram

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In the following diagram image, what are the ?. For the 0.8, is it supposed to be not A given B? And, is the 0.933 Not A given not B? Thank you.

[image: Conditional probability tree diagram]

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly as you say. Conditional probabilities are probabilities. Thus, $P(A\mid B)+P(\neg A\mid B)=1$, just like $P(A)+P(\neg A)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that: $$P(A\mid B)+P(A^{\complement}\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}+\frac{P(A^{\complement}\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A\cap B)+P(A^{\complement}\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(B)}{P(B)}=1$$